# Why is my ajax GET request coming back with an empty array?

Tags: html, jquery, sql, get

I'm querying from AWS Athena using athena-express. I'm using a get method to return certain data, and an AJAX call in the front end to start the query when a user enters a specific value with a req.body input. When I do this input in postman, I get data back successfully. However, when I try it with the AJAX call I just get back an empty array. I'm not sure if I'm inputting the value of req.body correctly.

**This is the athena config with query at the bottom.**

```
require('dotenv').config()

const AthenaExpress = require("athena-express"),
    aws = require("aws-sdk"),
    awsCredentials = {
        region: process.env.REGION,
        accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESSKEY,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRETACCESSKEY
    };

aws.config.update(awsCredentials);

//AthenaExpress config object
const athenaExpressConfig = {
    aws, /* required */
    // s3: process.env.S3BUCKET, /* optional */
    db: process.env.ATHENADB, /* optional */
    formatJson: true, /* optional default=true */
    retry: 200, /* optional default=200 */
    getStats: false /* optional default=false */
}


//Initializing AthenaExpress
const athenaExpress = new AthenaExpress(athenaExpressConfig);

module.exports = {

    getData: async (req, res) => {
        const { building_abbreviation } = req.body
        try {
            // I know this is a bad way of inputting variables for a query, but this is the only way I can do it using athena-express
            let results = await athenaExpress.query(`SELECT * FROM building_meter_metadata WHERE building_abbreviation = '${building_abbreviation}' ORDER BY building_abbreviation`)                  
            console.log(results)
            return res.json(results)
       } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the express route**

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const athenaController = require('../config/athena')

router.get('/getathena', athenaController.getData)

module.exports = router
```

**This is the ajax call**

```
  $('.search').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($(".building").val()) //This is the value that should be passed to building_abbreviation as req.body
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getathena',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
                building_abbreviation: $('.building').val()
            }
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
    })
```

**This is the HTML, just a simple select dropdown with a few building names to test receiving data.**

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
                <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Options</label>
                <select name="building_abbreviation" class="form-select building" id="inputGroupSelect01">
                    <option selected>Choose...</option>
                    <option>ACB</option>
                    <option>ADH</option>
                    <option>AHG</option>
                </select>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary search" type="button">Search</button>
            </div>
```

**And in the console I get back an empty array, however, when I run the query in postman I get back the correct data. Picture below**

```
ACB //This is the value that should be passed to building_abbreviation as req.body
{
    "Items": []
}
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: GET requests don't have a request body - try a POST instead

Comment: Thanks that was my issues, I didn't even think about POST. Woops lol